# OpenGL: dynamically change loaded vertices

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

Used: Qt 5.8 and QOpenGLxxx classes. OpenGL: Core 3.3.

I'm drawing a sphere and projecting plots of functions on it ([Riemmann sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sphere)). A user may change its radius dynamically by a slider, but I'm unsure what to do with vertices of already evaluated and projected function in that case. Personally I see two options:

1. Use mapping of the VBO data and modify data. Or use glBufferSubData.
2. Remove the VBO and create it again with updated plot info.

There at least 400 vertices, might be more, so the question of performance is crucial (well, it's crucial everywhere, though). What do you think?

Comment: There's a million possible answers to a question like this. Show us some of the code you've written, and your current attempt at solving this problem. A [mcve] would be good.

Comment: 400 vertices is close to nothing, so not really performance critical. However, a projection of the vertices onto a sphere can be done in the shaders directly by the GPU, so there is no need to reproject it on the CPU at all.

Comment: @derhass, hmm, yeah, you're right. It's just 4800 bytes in there, I made a rush judgement.

However, shaders are dealing with other kind of data too, which doesn't require a projection. How could they both be combined?

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented the first option with QOpenGLBuffer::map() and it worked just great. From given options, it's the only one that does not allocate/deallocate memory but merely maps it on the CPU memory, so, I think, for this case it's perfect. The code is sort of this:

```
void SphereRadiusChanged(float new_radius)
{
   m_vbo.bind();

   VertexClass* vbo_data = static_cast<VertexClass*>( m_vbo.map(QOpenGLBuffer::WriteOnly) );

   if(vbo_data == nullptr)
   {
      ...
   }

   // Here make necessary transformations.
   ...

   m_vbo.unmap();

   m_vbo.release();
}
```

Probably before that you'll have to make QOpenGLWidget's context current. That function executed inside that class's method, so I didn't do it.